# How to read in data just the once when using a tabcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I feel like I'm missing something and this should not be too hard.
I'm reading in some data in the initial scene in my app.
I've got a singleton and I make the call in `viewDidLoad` to `singleton.getData()`.

This initial scene is part of a tab controller. And while I thought `viewDidLoad` would only get called once for each scene I'm pretty sure it's being called a few times during the lifecycle of my app.

So just wondering if there is a way to ensure a function call to retrieve some data only happens once.

Comment: Maybe you can show your singleton codes and your viewdidload

Comment: You could call singleton.getData() in your app delegate instad. Since each time you change tab each view will call viewDidLoad. So if you wanna avoid it being called several times remove it from a view related controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` will be called when selected tab is changed, you can change the place you call `getData`.

If you want to call `getData` in `viewDidLoad` and be sure it won't be called multiple times you can create a flag and check, if it is previously called or not.

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private static var getDataCalled = false

    func getData() {
        if Singleton.getDataCalled {
            return
        }
        Singleton.getDataCalled = true

        // request data
        print("data requested")
    }
}


Singleton.sharedInstance.getData()
Singleton.sharedInstance.getData()
```

Calling `getData` multiple times print data requested only once.